# Angular 2 e material.angular.io

Tags: angular

Exemplo com o nome "Table retrieving data through HTTP", https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples.

Mas mudei para buscar da base de dados. As informações vem do banco de dados.

Sempre dá este erro:

**Meu código**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import { Estado } from '../model/estado.model';
import { EstadoService } from './estado.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-estado',
  templateUrl: './estado.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./estado.component.css']
})
  export class EstadoComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
    displayedColumns = ['pais', 'descricao', 'sigla'];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Estado>;

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    estados: Estado[];

    constructor(private router: Router, private estadoService : EstadoService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

      this.estadoService.todos().
      subscribe( 
        (data :any) => { 
          this.estados = data.lista;
      });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }

    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
      filterValue = filterValue.trim(); 
      filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); 
      this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    }
  }
```

Coloquei um breakpoint nestas instruções:

1º) **this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();**, dentro do método: **ngAfterViewInit()**
2º) **this.estados = data.lista;**, dentro do método **ngOnInit()**.

Ao entrar na tela ele para no 1º breakpoint, falado acima e depois no 2º breakpoint, falado acima. Faz a consulta no servidor java, banco de dados. Retorna corretamente as informações do servidor.

O problema é que ele não faz a paginação correta do componente.

Não faz a busca conforme está no exemplo.

Segue as imagens.

[image]

[image]

Não consegui evolui.

**HTML do componente**

> ```
> <div class="example-header">
>   <mat-form-field>
>     <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" 
>       placeholder="Pesquisa na tabela de estado">
>   </mat-form-field>
> </div>
>
> <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
>
>   <mat-table [dataSource]="estados" matSort>
>
>     <ng-container matColumnDef="pais">
>       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> País </mat-header-cell>
>       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.pais.descricao}} </mat-cell>
>     </ng-container>
>
>     <ng-container matColumnDef="descricao">
>       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Descrição </mat-header-cell>
>       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.descricao}} </mat-cell>
>     </ng-container>
>
>     <!-- Color Column -->
>     <ng-container matColumnDef="sigla">
>       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Abreviação </mat-header-cell>
>       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.abreviacao}} </mat-cell>
>     </ng-container>
>
>     <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
>     <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
>     </mat-row>
>   </mat-table>
>
>   <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Guilherme, pode postar o html do seu componente?

Comment: @mercador postado o código html...

Comment: existe algum erro ocorrendo? Já tentou adicionar o atributo `#paginator` na tag `<mat-paginator>`?

Comment: Acabei de incluir e não funcionou.

Como disse, no meu entendimento

1º) this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(); - dentro do método: ngAfterViewInit() - informações vazias, isto é, não foi ao banco de dados fazer a consulta;


2º) this.estados = data.lista;, dentro do método ngOnInit() - Faz a consulta no banco de dados, mas mostra na tela sem adaptar ao componente.

Entendeu ?

Não existe erro nem no servidor e nem no navegador.